# virtual work and potential energy

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I was just going through the thermal and elastic buckling of bars & plates ,I found some researchers use virtual work to derive the equations, another researchers use potential energy in other side..
 SO,In which problems that the principle of  potential energy more efficient to use than virtual work ?

Thanks

Comment: any help , idea?

Comment: Hi Soul. You will probably find more luck and opinions over on the <a href="http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-engineering">Engineering stack exchange</a>. This is really a question in mechanical engineering/continuum mechanics.